# Does a subgroup have to use the same operations as its parent group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading through some [lecture notes on Modern Algebra](http://math.mit.edu/%7Emckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_2.pdf), and came across this definition of a subgroup:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subset of $G$. We say that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, if the restriction to $H$ of the rule of multiplication and inverse makes $H$ into a group.

It seems implied that the operations are the same for $H$ as for $G$, but it's not explicitly stated. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) seems to be more explicit:

> Given a group $G$ under a binary operation $∗$, a subset $H$ of $G$ is called a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ also forms a group under the operation $∗$. More precisely, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if the restriction of $∗$ to $H \times H$ is a group operation on $H$.

However, this got me wondering if there ever could be a situation where a subgroup could have different operations than its parent group. For example, take the real numbers without 0 ($\mathbb{R}^*$) as $G$, with standard multiplication and inversion. Could I (hypothetically) construct a subgroup $H$ and define a new multiplication and inverse operation for it? If that wouldn't be a subgroup, is there a name for a group $H$ that's a subset of a group $G$ but has different operations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  That wouldn't be a subgroup

Comment: To be considered a subgroup, it must be a group with the same operation as in the "parent" group. If it is a subset but you define a different operation, then it's not a subgroup. Groups are more than just sets, they are sets *with operations*.  For $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$, you need the set $H$ to be a subset of $G$, **and** the operation on $H$ to be a "suboperation" of the operation on $G$.

Comment: Ok, so subgroups have to use the same multiplication and inversion as their parent group. That makes sense. Is there a different name for a group $H$ with that relation to another group $G$?

Comment: “ the restriction to  of the rule of multiplication and inverse makes  into a group.” That’s explicit, although perhaps a fairly technical way of saying what you are saying.

Comment: If you mean, is there a name for a subset of a group that happens to be a group with a different operation, then the answer is "no". There is no name for being a subset with a different operation on it. For instance, we don't talk about the positive reals under multiplication as being anything with respect to the real numbers under addition.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Arturo, that's what I was wondering.